# Three.js Cannon.js Cylinder rotates weirdly

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics, quaternions, cannon.js

I'm trying to use `CANNON.js` with `three.js`. All is working well with cube, sphere, and plane, but now when I try with Cylinder, it is rotating weirdly. I do NOT want to rotate the three.js object to match the CANNON.js object. Is there a way I can adjust the cannon.body? Here is a demonstration.

[image]

This is my code:

```js
let body = new PHYSICS.Body({shape: new PHYSICS.Cylinder(radiusTop, radiusBottom, height, segments), mass: 1});

body.linearDamping = 0.31;
```

Thanks!